# How can i suppress logs from webpack when using react hot reloading?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux, webpack-dev-server, react-hot-loader

I am using this react redux starter kit https://github.com/coryhouse/pluralsight-redux-starter and i am getting the following outputs in my console

```
[HMR] connected
```

I tried to toggle the following fields in the web-pack config to true and false but it doesn't help

```
  noInfo: true,
  debug: false,
```

How can i turn these logs off?

Comment: Try `devServer: {
    stats: 'errors-only'
  }`

Answer (score 1):

Tried many solutions, the dev server option `clientLogLevel: "none"` had the closest meaning. But couldn't get it working.

Then I found a workaround:

1. Run your app with `NODE_ENV=development`; for that go to `package.json` and update `scripts`:

   ```
   "scripts": {
     "build": "webpack",
     "start": "NODE_ENV=production webpack-dev-server --progress --inline --hot",
     "dev": "NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --progress --inline --hot"
   }
   ```
2. modify `webpack.config.js`:

   ```
   plugins: [
     new webpack.DefinePlugin({
       __DEVELOPMENT__: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
     })
   ],
   ```

   > The [DefinePlugin](http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#defineplugin) allows you to create global constants which can be
   >   configured at compile time.

   #### OR

   Replace `global.console.log` with a custom `console_log` that filters out `[HMR]` and `[WDS]` logs. See this [Github comment](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/109#issuecomment-143189783).

   Add the below code to your `development.js` (a file which is conditionally appended to the `entry` in `webpack.config.js` based on the value `process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'`)

   ```
   (function(global) {
       var console_log = global.console.log
       global.console.log = function() {
           if (!(
               arguments.length == 1 &&
               typeof arguments[0] === 'string' &&
               arguments[0].match(/^\[(HMR|WDS)\]/)
           )) {
               console_log.apply(global.console,arguments)
           }
       }
   })(window)
   ```
3. `npm run dev`

   If you've used DefinePlugin, then we now have global constant `__DEVELOPMENT__` === `true` on client side. So on every refresh you can do this:

   ```
   if (__DEVELOPMENT__) {
     console.clear();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

On version >= 4.0.0 of Webpack You can keep the hot reload feature but limit the logs to errors under devServer like below:

```
devServer: {
  hot: true,
  client: {
    overlay: false,
    logging: 'error',
  }
  ...
}
```

You can find more info about it on https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#logging